# Serialize() on symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have moved my `symfony2` script to another server. One of my script uses data from database which are serialized symfony2 entities.

Now, on one of my pages I get the following error:

```
 Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 952 of 958 bytes
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
```

As it was working before I think that it has something to do with server configuration.

Do I need any PHP/mySQL extensions to use `serialize()` ?

My `phpinfo()` files:

- Old environment: http://files.mage.pl/OldPhpInfo.pdf
- New environment: http://files.mage.pl/NewPhpInfo.pdf

Comment: check (and report in the question) the version of php and the module installed in both the environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was connected with database encoding. I have change mySQL encoding in my.cnf into:

```
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci' 
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8' 

[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

and the problem is gone.